# C++ Forward Declaration of Objects

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

i'm trying to figure out how to forward declare objects where new objects are storing other new objects for example:

A Queue, holding Nodes, these Nodes hold Data items which hold 2 Lists or preferably 2 Queues.

Here is my Data.h

```
#ifndef DATA_H_
#define DATA_H_

class List;
class Data {
public:
    Data();
    Data(int aID);
    virtual ~Data();
    virtual int getID();
    virtual void setID(int aID);
private:
    int ID;
    List *listOne;
    List *listTwo;
};

#endif /* DATA_H_ */
```

And my Data.c

```
#include "Data.h"
#include "List.h"

Data::Data() {
    listOne = new List();
    listTwo = new List();
    Data::ID = 0;
}

Data::Data(int aID) {
    Data::listOne = new List();
    Data::listTwo = new List();
    Data::ID = aID;
}

Data::~Data() {
    delete(listOne);
    delete(listTwo);
}

int Data::getID() {
    return Data::ID;
}

void Data::setID(int aID) {
    Data::ID = ID;
}
```

The error message:

```
..\Data.cpp: In constructor 'Data::Data()':
..\Data.cpp:12:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class List'
  listOne = new List();
                       ^
In file included from ..\Data.cpp:8:0:
..\Data.h:11:7: note: forward declaration of 'class List'
 class List;
       ^
..\Data.cpp:13:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class List'
  listTwo = new List();
                      ^
In file included from ..\Data.cpp:8:0:
..\Data.h:11:7: note: forward declaration of 'class List'
 class List;
       ^
..\Data.cpp: In constructor 'Data::Data(int)':
..\Data.cpp:18:29: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class List'
  Data::listOne = new List();
                             ^
In file included from ..\Data.cpp:8:0:
..\Data.h:11:7: note: forward declaration of 'class List'
 class List;
       ^
..\Data.cpp:19:28: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class List'
  Data::listTwo = new List();
                            ^
In file included from ..\Data.cpp:8:0:
..\Data.h:11:7: note: forward declaration of 'class List'
 class List;
       ^
..\Data.cpp: In destructor 'virtual Data::~Data()':
..\Data.cpp:24:18: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [-Wdelete-incomplete]
  delete(listOne);
                  ^
..\Data.cpp:24:18: warning: invalid use of incomplete type 'class List'
In file included from ..\Data.cpp:8:0:
..\Data.h:11:7: note: forward declaration of 'class List'
 class List;
       ^
..\Data.cpp:24:18: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined
  delete(listOne);
                  ^
..\Data.cpp:25:17: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [-Wdelete-incomplete]
  delete(listTwo);
                 ^
..\Data.cpp:25:17: warning: invalid use of incomplete type 'class List'
In file included from ..\Data.cpp:8:0:
..\Data.h:11:7: note: forward declaration of 'class List'
 class List;
       ^
..\Data.cpp:25:17: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined
  delete(listTwo);
```

Now if I remove the forward delclaration in Data.h and have Data.h include List.h I will get: and result in a circular inheritance cycle

```
..\Data.h:25:2: error: 'List' does not name a type
  List *cpubursts;
  ^
..\Data.h:26:2: error: 'List' does not name a type
  List *iobursts;
```

How will I go about fixing this sort of setup?

Edit: List.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_

#include "Node.h"

namespace std {

class List {
private:
    Node *top;
public:
    List();
    virtual ~List();
    virtual Node* getTop();
    virtual void add(Node * linkedNode);
    virtual void remove(Node * linkedNode);
};

} /* namespace std */

#endif /* LIST_H_ */
```

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_

#include "Data.h"

namespace std {

class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(Data * aItem);
    virtual ~Node();
    virtual Node* getNext();
    virtual void setNext(Node * linkedNode);
    virtual Data* getData();
    virtual void setData(Data* item);
private:
    Node *next;
    Data *item;
};

} /* namespace std */

#endif /* NODE_H_ */
```

Comment: Can we see List.h?

Comment: What is `List` doing inside `namespace std`?

Comment: We were told to just use std namespace for everything as a standard for code by my teacher

Comment: If your teacher tells you to use namspace std like this, find another teacher.

Comment: "The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified."

Comment: `class List` and `class Node` have no business being in `namespace std`. There are very [specific reasons for very specific cases for extending  namespace `std`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std), *none* of which are applicable here. The *correct* solution, contrary to what was selected, is to remove those classes from namespace `std`; *not* add them in all declarations including forward decls. If your instructor told you to do this, either you misunderstood them (happens often) or they're flat-wrong (happens more often than you'd think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining `List` inside the `std` namespace, and forward declaring it outside of that. When  you do this, you're saying "there's a class called List in the global namespace", which of course there isn't.

What you need to express is "there's a class called `List` inside the `std` namespace", which can be done as follows:

```
namespace std {
    class List;
}

class Data {
    /* your class */
};
```

I would question why you'd want to define your own class inside of namespace `std`, but that's beside the point.

Comment: I believe this was it, thank you so much, I will try to properly run this and test.

Comment: @user2946986 glad to hear it; if it works, please mark my answer as accepted. If it doesn't, update your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

When creating an object, the compiler has to know the class, so you have to include the header defining it within you Data.cpp.

Note that using raw new and delete is not recommended, use a direct instance or use smartpointers. You may use a std::unique with a forward declartion, but make sure the full class definition is known when the compiler is about to emit the code for the destructor of the std::unique_ptr.

Comment: But I do have "#include "List.h"" inside "Data.cpp" to use when creating new Lists, adding, removing, deleting etc.

Comment: The question shows that this is included, we just don't see the content